# What are examples and what are they used for?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The directory layout of a Rust project should look like this ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/guide/project-layout.html))

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── benches
│   └── large-input.rs
├── examples
│   └── simple.rs
├── src
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── another_executable.rs
│   ├── lib.rs
│   └── main.rs
└── tests
    └── some-integration-tests.rs
```

What is the file `simple.rs` under examples? How do I execute it? How should the file look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examples are useful in library crates to show how the crate is used.

An example can be an executable with a main method or a library; it can either be in a single file `examples/example-name.rs` or consist of several files in a subdirectory `examples/example-name/`, with the main method in `main.rs`.  To compile a library example you need to specify its crate type in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[[example]]
name = "example-name"
crate-type = ["lib"]
```

Examples are compiled by `cargo test` to ensure that they are up to date with the crate. You can run a specific executable example by

```
cargo run --example <example-name>
```

and selectively build any example with

```
cargo build --example <example-name>
```

[This is documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#examples) in the [Cargo Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/).

Comment: Could you add to the answer what the file should look like; I would suppose it should be a binary (ie, have a `fn main()` item), but without clicking the links I cannot be sure.